# How can I find the right driver for my RAID controller?

Tags: drivers, raid, controller

I have a RAID controller that I used to have a driver for, but after rebuilding windows, the controller no longer shows up.

I don't remember who made it, or really anything about it. How can I track down the correct driver for this controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all find the device in the Windows device manager and write down
the PCI device vendor ID and device ID. These should be two HEX numbers -
one indicating the vendor ID and the second the device ID of the controller.

After that go the the following web site and find the exact model of the
RAID controller using the vendor and device IDs.

http://www.pcidatabase.com/

Once you will have the exact vendor name and the model name of the controller
there should be no problem to find the driver.

Answer (score 0):

If it is integrated on the motherboard, go to the motherboard manufacturers website to track it down.

If it is an add in card, pull the card out and see if there is a make and model number printed on it, then go to their website to download the driver.

Or you can try this software to try and determine what raid controller you have

http://www.zhangduo.com/udi.html

.